# Auto Update form field from integer to decimal

Tags: javascript, integer, decimal, auto-update

I have two form fields for users to enter weight in kg and length in meters, most users consider the length in centimeters which gives wrong calculations. can I have a way to auto update form in the case of entering integer ? ( e.g. 170 to be automatically converted to 1.7 ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may check if the value is an integer like that:

```
var isInt = function(n) {
   return n % 1 === 0;
}
```

Here is a js fiddle showing this in action http://jsfiddle.net/krasimir/6e72q/

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="field"/>
```

JS

```
var field = document.getElementById("field");
field.addEventListener("change", function() {
    var value = field.value;
    if(isInt(value)) {
        field.value = value = value / 100;
    }
});
var isInt = function(n) {
   return n % 1 === 0;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks @Krasimir, this was exactly what I needed. But, I don't know why it's not working even when I tested in a simple html page it didn't work. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: That's because probably you used my code directly. You need to change the id of the field in getElementById function.

Comment: I'm using the same code for testing in a blank html file with the input form and js only.

Comment: Ok, make a jsfiddle with the same code and I'll be able to help you. From what you say I think you didn't use the correct id in getElementById function.

Comment: No, it worked now, I had to move javascript from HEAD to bottom of the file. Many thanks @Krasimir. :)

Comment: You are welcome. It will be nice if you mark my answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the value of the field for 'dot' with onchange event

```
/\./.test(fieldValue)
```

if it's false, convert that value to number (+, Number(), parseInt()) and divide, then update the value property of that input field